# Node.JS, Are my passwords safe in RAM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I have a little webApp that allows people to create personnal pages using Express and Node.JS. Every page is an object, which means you can create a new one using: `new privatePage(name, pswd)`, therefore all the passwords are stored in the pswd attribute of the object.

My question is, are they safe here, or is it easy to "hack" them?

**Edit:** My passwords only need to be stored for a maximum of 24 hours in average, as the pages delete themselves if they are inactive for a short amount of time.

Comment: It's always easy to hack them when you are in control of the OS on which your app runs. But no, it's not easy to hack them from the outside.

Comment: Do you intend for them to be "stored" for a longer time in those instances?

Comment: "Hours" is long. "for the time of a single request" is short. Do you plan for your application to store everything in-memory only? So if the app crashes and has to be restarted, all pages are gone?

Comment: Well, I don't care so much about the server crashing, as it is more of a theorical question than a practical one

Comment: The theoretical advice is to always hash them. You cannot completely prevent them from occurring in the RAM, but you should limit their time there to the shortest possible. Storing them unhashed for their entire life time (in your case 24h) is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are absolutely **NOT SAFE**.

You store them using bcrypt which is the latest and the best hashing algorithm being used by the world. And if you use this the passwords which are stored in you database are absolutely safe.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Well, the password is in RAM when received and supplied to bcrypt so I guess this is not safe either. NIST suggests usinf PBKDF2 but what do they know. ;-) Define "absolutely safe"?

Comment: @zaph If you use bcrypt, the passwords are in RAM only for a few milliseconds before passing it to bcrypt for hashing! It's much better than storing them in RAM in plaintext for 24 hrs. PBKDF2 is old fashioned & a GPU can easily create rainbow tables when compared to bcrypt. Care to share the link to the NIST document you mentioned above that suggests PBKDF2 over bcrypt for others? When is the NIST document last updated you mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "safe".

As security best practice, you should assume nothing is safe in RAM. Bad software and OS code that can have vulnerabilities that result in buffer overflows, can allow a skilled attacker gain control over your server's segment of memory which can include sensitive data like your page passwords. It is worth noting that exploring buffer overflow issues is a difficult task, but with existent of Internet, anyone can create a tool that any [script kiddies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie) can run. Therefore, it is best practice for sensitive data to be short lived in memory to reduce the risk of exposure to these kind of issues.

Now, on the other hand, you may have a very solid policy on updating security patches on your servers and do it as fast as security issues are announced. In that case, I would say the risk is lower for you, but it doesn't take away the chance of hacking 100%. This is why I first say it depends how "safe" you want your environment be.

Comment: Oh, I guess most DBs encryprion is not safe, make that encryption in general, because the key must be in RAM at some point unless you have an HSM.